# Otimizando imports no python

Tags: python-3.x, import

Tenho uma pasta que contém vários arquivos com a extensão .py e dentro de cada arquivo tem um dicionário com os dados dos monstros que eu preciso iniciar. Porém, quanto maior for a quantidade de monstros que eu criar, maior vai ficando essa lista de imports. Tem algum jeito de importar toda a pasta e todos os dicionários de uma vez?

```
from units import Monster
from data.creatures.monster_list.rat import rat
from data.creatures.monster_list.snake import snake
from data.creatures.monster_list.scorpion import scorpion
from data.creatures.monster_list.lion import lion
from data.creatures.monster_list.wolf import wolf
from data.creatures.monster_list.warlock import warlock
MONSTERS = [rat,snake,scorpion,lion,wolf,warlock]
```

Comment: Por que cada dicionário é definido em arquivos separados? Poderia definir todos eles no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Poderia, mas queria deixar separado pra facilitar as modificações e pra não ficar um único arquivo gigante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O ideal aí é ter um esquema para fazer uma importação dinâmica de arquivos na mesma pasta. Esse código pode rodar no arquivo `__init__` de uma pasta - e assim que você importar aquela pasta como um pacote, todos os arquivos `.py` da mesma são lidos.

Tradicionalmente, a forma de se importar um módulo a partir de uma string (ou seja, um dado, em contraste com o nome do módulo digitado diretamente no programa como parâemtro para o comando `import`) é com a chamada `__import__`.  Pr questões históricas, no entanto, seu uso é mais complicado do que precisa ser -com um único parâmetro ela acaba retornando o pacote raiz da string que você passou (no seu exemplo, o pacote  `data`)

Então, de forma genérica, é possível fazer um import que traga tudo o que tiver no diretório. No seu caso, como você quer disponibilizar as classes importadas numa estrutura de dados (uma lista), pode valer a pena fazer algo mais direcionado:

```py
from importlib import import_module
from pathlib import Path

def import_creatures(package_name):
    root_package = import_module("package_name")
    package_path = Path(root_package.__file__).parent
    creature_classes = []
    for source_file in package_path.glob("*.py"):
        module = import_module(source_file)
        name = source_file.stem
        # Tenta importar a classe se tiver nome comecando com letra maiuscula também
        cls = getattr(module, name, getattr(module, name.title(), None))
        if not cls:
            continue
        creature_classes.append(cls)
    return creature_classes

MONSTERS = import_creatures("data.creatures.monster_list")
```

Esse código tenta sempre pegar a classe que tem o mesmo nome que o arquivo, como no seu exemplo - mas também é possível introspectar o módulo (pegando `module.__dict__.items()` por exemplo), e pegar todos os objetos que sejam subclasse de uma classe específica - se todas as suas herdam de "Monster" por exemplo - daí você pode tranquilamente ter mais de uma definição de monstro por arquivo, e ainda tem liberdade para o nome das classes.

---

Mudando de assunto -e esse jogo aí? Vai estar liberado? Tá em repositório público? Podemos contribuir?? :-)

---

Uma outra nota, como o primeiro pacote do seu nome de importação é `data`, provavelmente seu projeto ainda não está estruturado ele mesmo como um pacote de Python que pode ser instalado - e só vai funcionar se você rodar o programa principal da pasta onde ele está (e aí, nessa pasta tem a pasta `data`, mas que para o Python é um pacote independente do seu projeto).

O ideal é que o diretório do seu projeto tenha um `__init__.py`, e você trabalhe de uma pasta acima, onde com um arquivo `setup.py` mínimo, você pode digitar `pip install --editable .` para que seu jogo seja visto como "todo". Nesse caso, os imports vão mudar pra `meujogo.data.creatures....` , ou com um "." na frente - `.data.creatures...` - mas o projeto todo fica com um "feeling" de um único produto - é bem mais legal.

O setup.py que você precisa é algo como:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='route_optimizer',
    version='0.1',
    author='Thomas Caio',
    py_packages=['meujogo'],
    install_requires=[],

)
```

Comment: Po... Valeu! To fazendo esse jogo com intenção de praticar POO. To me batendo pra compartilhar no github, queria deixar público pra que o pessoal possa ajudar com dicas. Sou novo na área e esse negócio de importação sempre me quebra as pernas.

Comment: Legal - justamente se quer usar P.O.O. não eram pra ser "dicionários" com os dados  dos montros - vamos ver se passamos eles pra subclasses

Comment: É que com dicionário eu consigo armazenar os dados dos monstros em uma variável, foi o jeito que eu pensei pra poder retornar novas instâncias de monstros, só repassando os dados deles.

https://github.com/ThomasCaio/.RPG
Consegui colocar o projeto no github. Dê uma olhada!

Comment: não - o jeito que você está pensando dicionários é o que é pra fazer com subclasses - classes que herdam da classe monstro. E o que você está criando como "instâncias" -deveriam ser essas classes também. (para quem estiver acompanhando, está no github aqui: https://github.com/ThomasCaio/.RPG/tree/9f6f38a7d10303b0bed7de434a3c279c266d57ae

Comment: Se puder me dê um exemplo desse método pra criar novas instâncias de monstro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simples de fazer os imports é importar todos os arquivos da pasta:

```
from data.creatures.monster_list import *
```

O problema é que isso importaria os arquivos e para acessar as classes precisaria fazer `Arquivo.Classe`. Se isso não for um problema pra você, é uma ótima solução.